# Taxonomy view doesn't display products

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, commerce

This is the situation.

I have a product type and in this type i use a term reference field. Then i add some products.
Next step, i create the product displays using the product reference field (the default one).
So far so good. Then i use views and enable the build in view for taxonomies which in non commerce site shows the nodes for each taxonomy. Now it displaying nothing. I tried to add the product relationship but still nothing.

Any ideas?? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you have the devel themer enable? I have the problem with some filters lately..it was not displaying the filter. The problem was that I have the devel themer enable..
2. Are you using ubercart or commerce? if you are using commerce make sure to have associate the taxonomy with the display..here it is a little reference, that video helped me with my taxonomy and give me the right path [Building a Drupal commerce catalog](http://vimeo.com/22748684)

Comment: I use DC. I just associated the taxonomy with the display although i do believe that the taxonomy term should be in the product type instead because it's an attribute of the product. It looks a little sloppy filling two different forms with attributes in both of them...